# Google map clustering is not working for small count of cordinates

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-layout, google-maps-markers

I am using the `Google Map Clustering` demo application [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering) to play with it. As per in the example offset are following:

```
private void readItems() throws JSONException {
    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.radar_search);
    List<MyItem> items = new MyItemReader().read(inputStream);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        double offset = i / 60d;
        for (MyItem item : items) {
            LatLng position = item.getPosition();
            double lat = position.latitude + offset;
            double lng = position.longitude + offset;
            MyItem offsetItem = new MyItem(lat, lng);
            mClusterManager.addItem(offsetItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Clustering is working perfectly for large numbers of coordinates (=>5). To understand let's take two scenarios:

- First scenario 
  I am loading two coordinates through following data file:

  ```
  [
   { "lat" : 28.5092163, "lng" : 77.4135367 },
   { "lat" : 28.5102148, "lng" : 77.411671 },
   { "lat" : 28.5092163, "lng" : 77.4135367 },
   { "lat" : 28.5102148, "lng" : 77.411671 },
   { "lat" : 28.5092163, "lng" : 77.4135367 },
   { "lat" : 28.5092163, "lng" : 77.4135367 },
   { "lat" : 28.5092163, "lng" : 77.4135367 },
   { "lat" : 28.5102148, "lng" : 77.411671 },
   { "lat" : 28.5102148, "lng" : 77.411671 },
   { "lat" : 28.5102148, "lng" : 77.411671 },
   { "lat" : 28.5102148, "lng" : 77.411671 },
   { "lat" : 28.5102148, "lng" : 77.411671 },
   { "lat" : 28.5102148, "lng" : 77.411671 },
   { "lat" : 28.5102148, "lng" : 77.411671 }
  ]
  ```

  As we can see in above data file that count of `{ "lat" : 28.5102148, "lng" : 77.411671 }` is 9 and count of `{ "lat" : 28.5092163, "lng" : 77.4135367 },` is 5. Screenshot of the emulator:

[image]

- Second scenario
  I am loading two coordinates through following data file:

  ```
  [
   { "lat" : 28.5102148, "lng" : 77.411671 },
   { "lat" : 28.5092163, "lng" : 77.4135367 },
   { "lat" : 28.5102148, "lng" : 77.411671 },
   { "lat" : 28.5092163, "lng" : 77.4135367 },
   { "lat" : 28.5092163, "lng" : 77.4135367 },
   { "lat" : 28.5092163, "lng" : 77.4135367 },
   { "lat" : 28.5102148, "lng" : 77.411671 },
   { "lat" : 28.5102148, "lng" : 77.411671 },
   { "lat" : 28.5102148, "lng" : 77.411671 },
   { "lat" : 28.5102148, "lng" : 77.411671 },
   { "lat" : 28.5102148, "lng" : 77.411671 },
   { "lat" : 28.5102148, "lng" : 77.411671 },
   { "lat" : 28.5102148, "lng" : 77.411671 }
  ]
  ```

  As we can see in above data file that count of `{ "lat" : 28.5102148, "lng" : 77.411671 }` is 9 and count of `{ "lat" : 28.5092163, "lng" : 77.4135367 },` is 4. Screenshot of the emulator:

[image]

So, the problem is whenever I am passing less than 5 coordinators for the same `Lat,Lng`. Google map wont's showing the cluster. It supposed to be show as `9` and `4`.

I tried to follow the documentation but nothing is heling me out. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried doing `mClusterManager.cluster()` right after the `for` loop to force a re-cluster?

Comment: I tried but got the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so many attempts. I looked at the `Cluster` library [code](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering/view/DefaultClusterRenderer.java#L106) and found:

```
private int mClusterSize = 4;
```

Change it to as per your convenience.